# Error executing DDL "drop sequence player_seq" via JDBC Statement

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008

In my Entity class I have written this code.

```
 @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "player_Sequence")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "player_Sequence", sequenceName = "PLAYER_SEQ")
```

But showing below error.

```
2018-12-19 13:49:54 WARN  o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "drop sequence team_seq" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "drop sequence team_seq" via JDBC Statement
```

Comment: Please _always_ add the full stackTrace. Additionally `drop sequence team_seq` implies there is / was a sequence named `team_seq` defined in your entity model but source code is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have update application.properties file with below code.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
```

I have to use `@GeneratedValue` in Entity class instead of Sequence.

```
@Entity
public class Player {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "num")
    private int num;
    @Column(name = "position")
    private String position;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "team_id", nullable = false)
        private Team team;
    public Player() {
    }
```